# Why does this directory comparison program not detect an extra file?

Tags: python

I have a directory comparison program (based on the example given in the docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) which doesn't find an extra file which I put in a subdirectory to test it. The program is:

```
import sys
from filecmp import dircmp

def print_diff_files(dcmp):
    for name in dcmp.diff_files:
        print("diff_file %s found in %s and %s" % (name, dcmp.left, dcmp.right))
    for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
        print_diff_files(sub_dcmp)

dcmp = dircmp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) 
print_diff_files(dcmp)
print(dcmp.left_only)
print(dcmp.right_only)
```

The right_only list should have something in it, except it's just []. Why is this?

Comment: It would help if you included directory listings for the files and directories that you're running this script on, as well as the actual arguments.

Comment: But it recognizes the directories. I don't get an error message saying they're not there.

Comment: No, I mean include more information in your question. Without information about the files that your program is operating on it's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: The directories are duplicates - one is a back up. I added a text file to a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filecmp.dircmp` does not compare files recursively. If you want `dircmp.left_only` and `dircmp.right_only` to be recursive, you'll have to do it yourself like you do for `dircmp.diff_files`.

Move your `print(dcmp.left_only)` and `print(dcmp.right_only)` inside your recursive function `print_diff_files`:

```
import sys
from filecmp import dircmp

def print_diff_files(dcmp):
    for name in dcmp.diff_files:
        print("diff_file %s found in %s and %s" % (name, dcmp.left, dcmp.right))
    if dcmp.left_only:
        print('%s: %s ' % (dcmp.left, dcmp.left_only))
    if dcmp.right_only:
        print('%s: %s ' % (dcmp.right, dcmp.right_only))
    for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
        print_diff_files(sub_dcmp)

dcmp = dircmp(r'c:\temp\t', r'c:\temp\s')
print_diff_files(dcmp)
```

Comment: Thanks - got it working. I think it may be because I was calling dcmp outside the function's namespace though.

Answer (score 1):

I made minor changes to blhsing's program, as shown:

```
#diffdir.py - compares directories and lists shallow differences; use python3
import sys
from filecmp import dircmp

def print_diff_files(dcmp):
    for name in dcmp.diff_files:
        print("\nDiff file: %s found in %s and %s" % (name, dcmp.left, dcmp.right))
    for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
        print_diff_files(sub_dcmp)
    if dcmp.left_only:
        print("\nLeft only:", dcmp.left_only)
    if dcmp.right_only:
        print("\nRight only:", dcmp.right_only)

dcmp = dircmp(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) 
print_diff_files(dcmp)
print()
```